# Ponteiro de struct para struct

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Olá, eu havia feito uma pergunta anterior sobre este problema, porem consegui solucionar mas não aprender sobre o problema propriamente dito então eu tentei isolar o mesmo criando um código especifico para este problema e gostaria que alguém me ensinasse o que esta acontecendo e porque é errado.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    char name[256];
    //char *name;
} person;

typedef struct Population
{
    person p;
    int num;
    struct Population *next;
}people;

void insere_person(person *p){
   printf("insira um nome: ");
   scanf(" %s", p->name);
}

void insere_people(people *ps){
    printf("insira um nome: ");
    scanf(" %s", ps->p.name);
    printf("insira um numero: ");
    scanf(" %d", &ps->num);
}

void insere_person_to_people(person *p, people *ps){
    insere_person(p);
    printf("insira um numero: ");
    scanf(" %d", &ps->num);
    ps->p = *p;
}

short vazia(people *ps){
    if(ps->next == NULL){ return 1; }
    else{ return 0; }
}

void insere_teste(people *ps){
    //char nome[256];
    people *new_ps = (people *)malloc(sizeof(people));
    printf("digite um nome:");
    scanf(" %s", ps->p.name);
    //scanf(" %s", nome);

    new_ps->p = ps->p;
    new_ps->next = NULL;

    if(vazia(ps)){
        ps->next = new_ps;
    }
    else{
        people *tmp = ps->next;
        while(tmp->next != NULL){
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = new_ps;
    }
}

void person_to_string(person *p){
    printf("person{nome:%s}\n", p->name);
}

void people_to_string(people *ps){
    printf("people{nome:%s, num:%d}\n", ps->p.name, ps->num);
}

void all_to_string(people *ps){
    if(vazia(ps)){
        printf("ninguem!\n");
        return;
    }
    else{
        people *tmp = ps->next;
        while(tmp != NULL){
            people_to_string(tmp);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}

void menu(person *p, people *ps){
    int op = -1;

    while(op != 0){
        printf("0 - sair\
        \n1 - insere pessoa\
        \n2 - insere populacao\
        \n3 - mostra pessoa\
        \n4 - mostra populacao\
        \nopcao: ");
        scanf(" %d", &op);

        switch(op){
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            insere_person(p);
            break;
        case 2:
            //insere_people(ps); // funciona
            //insere_person_to_people(p, ps); // funciona
            insere_teste(ps); // não funciona
            break;
        case 3:
            person_to_string(p);
            break;
        case 4:
            //people_to_string(ps);
            all_to_string(ps);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Opcao invalida.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    person p;
    people ps;

    menu(&p, &ps);

    return 0;
}
```

Então após testar diversas formas de inserir os dados eu percebi que no método "insere_teste()" ele da erro na linha:

```
scanf(" %s", ps->p.name);
```

Gostaria que alguém me explicasse este erro, pois como resolver eu já sei, mas não me adianta saber como resolver sem entender o que acontece.

Um outro ponto que gostaria de aprender é o porque estão todos sendo modificados juntos, sei que é um ponteiro que esta apontando para o mesmo endereço, mas gostaria de uma explicação mais didática para isto, pois na pratica eu já aprendi.

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro do seu código não acontece na linha

```
scanf(" %s", ps->p.name);
```

O problema é mais para frente em:

```
while(tmp->next != NULL){
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

A contece que é que `tmp->next` possui lixo, ou seja, possui um valor diferente de ***zero***, e quando `tmp` passa a ser `tmp->next`, não há um `next` para verificar no `while`. Isso gera o erro de memória.

Quando se trabalha com pilhas, listas e ponteiros, costuma iniciá-los com **0** para que as estruturas não retornem `true` assim evita erros desse tipo.

Como você não está usando ponteiros para instanciar sua lista, você deve atribuir ***NULL*** ou ***0*** ao `ps.next`, assim indicará que não existe um proximo item na sua lista.

main:

```
people ps;
// ps.next possui lixo (valor != 0)
ps.next = 0; // ao atribuir 0 para ps.next, é definido o final da lista
```

Assim quando chegar no laço, ira identificar o zero e encerará.

```
while(tmp->next != NULL){ // NULL == 0
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

---

Outra observação.

insere_teste:

```
if(vazia(ps)){
    ps->next = new_ps;
}
```

Essa condição deveria retornar **1** caso `ps` esteja vazio, mas `ps` nunca está vazio, pois é possível acessar os campos `p, num e next`, o certo de uma lista vazia seria um ponteiro com o valor **0**

```
int main(){
    person p;
    //people ps; // Lista com 1 registro
    people *ps = 0; // lista vazia

    menu(&p, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

> **O que mudaria no meu código?**

Ao invés de usar `people *ps` no métodos, passaria a ser `people **ps` (ponteiro duplo).

```
void insere_people(people **ps){
```

E para acessar o seu item para pegar o valor desejado tem que recolher o endereço dentro do ponteiro

```
(*ps)->next; // pega o valor dentro do ponteiro duplo
```

---

> **O que é um ponteiro duplo?**

O ponteiro duplo é um ponteiro que guarda outros ponteiro(Guardar o endereço de memória). Sua declaração é feita por `**`.

```
int var;
int *ptr; // ponteiro normal
int **ptr_d; // ponteiro duplo
```

Assim como já se sabe, a variável guarda um valor e o ponteiro simples guarda o endereço de memória da variável. Então o ponteiro duplo é responsável por guardar os endereços de memória das variáveis. Ex:

```
int var = 6;
int *ptr = &var;
int **ptr_d = &ptr;
printf("%i - %i - %i", var, *ptr, **ptr_d); // %i equivale a %d
```

**ptr_d -> ptr -> var**
`ptr_d` aponta para `ptr` que aponta para `var` ou seja, o endereço de memória que está salva o endereço de memória de `var` está salvo em `ptr_d`

Para entender melhor com exemplos acesse:

**[Main File - On github](https://github.com/brumazzi/pilha_stack/blob/master/main.c)**

**[Stack Struct - On github](https://github.com/brumazzi/pilha_stack/blob/master/stack.h)**

Comment: Poderia me explicar o que seria um ponteiro duplo e qual seria a diferença dele para um ponteiro normal?

Pois este é um código isolado apenas de um problema que eu tive e consegui resolver, no entanto resolver sem entender não adianta, se quiser eu posso postar aqui o código original (deixei no github, então possui as versões anteriores).

Comment: @bruno, acrescentei uma explicação sobre o ponteiro duplo, espero não ter ficado muito abstrato.

Comment: Certo, corrija-me se estiver errado, mas ao que eu entendi caso eu faça uma atribuição `**ptr_d = 7` ele mudará todos os demais valores, certo? Então um ponteiro duplo nada mais é que uma extensão do ponteiro simples, mas quando e porque é utilizado?

Comment: exatamente o valor é alterado assim. O ponteiro duplo costuma ser usando quando se quer alterar um ponteiro, como listas são normalmente feitas com um ponteiro sim (na maioria dos casos), é usando o ponteiro duplo para alterá-las, assim como no exemplo no link, onde o ponteiro é iniciado com `NULL` para definir um final.

Comment: Certo, mas agora fiquei um pouco confuso, eu entendi o COMO usar, mas não entendi o PORQUE usar, pois eu não poderia utilizar um ponteiro simples para este mesmo exemplo? O que faz com que seja mais correto, ou necessário criar um ponteiro para este ponteiro?

Comment: @bruno, O primeiro motivo é pela semântica do código, o segundo é pelo ponteiro ser responsável por armazenar endereços, é muito provável que de erro de memória ao tentar colocar um endereço em uma variável que não o suporta, isso porque cada tipo de variável precisa reservar uma quantidade **x** de memória, e os ponteiros já tem o espaço suficiente para isso, por isso que se usa ponteiros duplos para armazenar ponteiros.

Comment: Acho que entendi, mas vamos ver, o ponteiro duplo na verdade ele ira alocar um novo espaço de memória pra evitar conflitos ou estouros de buffers, é isso?

Comment: Não conflitos, mas buffers sim.

Comment: Então acho que agora sim eu entendi, vou tentar utilizar em projetos futuros, pois ai sim posso tirar a prova disso kkkk, muito obrigado.